# gstreamer, gstbasetransform, deriving SrcPad Caps from connected SinkPad

Tags: gstreamer

### Use-case

- In-Place Video transform, derived from **GstBaseTransformClass**
- Fixed Src/Sink templates ( "video/x-raw, fourcc=(string){ YV12, I420 }" )
- SrcPad resolution should be derived from the SinkPad resolution upon connection, and, is different from the SrcPad resolution

### Expected behavior

- accept_caps(SinkPad) is called just before connecting

  - accept_caps(SinkPad)

    - Validate the incoming connection GstCaps
    - Update Sink caps using 'gst_pad_set_caps(SinkPad, modifiedCaps)'
    - return true to approve the Caps
  - accept_caps(SinkPad)

    - Validate the incoming connection GstCaps
    - return true to approve the Caps

### Observed behavior

- accept_caps(SinkPad) is called

  - accept_caps(SinkPad)

    - gst_pad_is_linked(SinkPad) returns true, that is, **the SinkPad is already linked** so there is no meaning is changing it's caps...

### Problem at-hand

W/ my use-case, the SrcPad resolution can be derived only after the SinkPad is connected, as seen above, 'accept_caps' is called **only after** the sink is already connected, having that said, **what is the best way of dynamically setting the SinkPad Caps based on the connected SrcPad Caps ?**

Answer (score 0):

Your pads were already linked based on you template `video/x-raw, fourcc=(string){ YV12, I420 }`, which does not contain any resolution info.

You should override the [`transform_caps`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-libs/html/GstBaseTransform.html#GstBaseTransformClass.transform-caps) virtual method.  It is called before `accept_caps` and its purpose is "[...] given the pad in [one] direction and the given caps, what caps are allowed on the other pad in this element?"  So here you can put your resolution change.